# 3 model association in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-activerecord

i'm working on classified portal in which i have following 3 models

```
User (name,email)
Advertisement (title,body,user_id)
Bid (user_id,ad_id,price)
```

i have association between User and Advertisement as follow

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :advertisements
end

class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

Now i wanna define Bid model , i guess this is how it should look like ,

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :advertisement
end
```

and i should add has_many :bids in User and Advertisement model as well(i think so),

Now my question is, say User is logged in and he wants to bid for some advertisement , so on advertisements show page how should i integrate this bid form, and please do let me how should i define routes for this .

Rails 3.2.13

Ruby 2.0.0p0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at business logic of your app, there are two stories you have to implement

1) User can create advertisements (offers) (thats why you added user_id in Advertisement)

2) And user can bid on advertisements (thats simple has_many :through association)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bids
  has_many :advertisements, :through => :bids
  has_many :offers, class_name: "Advertisement", foreign_key: :user_id
end

class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, class_name:"User", foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :bids
  has_many :users, :through => :bids 
end

class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :advertisement
end
```

So now, if you want to get Advertisement author you need to call

```
a = Advertisement.last
a.author
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-31 06:13:20", updated_at: "2013-05-31 06:13:20"> 
a.users
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "bids" ON "users"."id" = "bids"."user_id" WHERE "bids"."advertisement_id" = 2
 => [#<User id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-31 06:13:20", updated_at: "2013-05-31 06:13:20">, #<User id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-31 06:13:20", updated_at: "2013-05-31 06:13:20">]
```

See, it makes last select through joining bids, while first one just selecting from users table. Now it works like you expect it to work.

**Anyway, answering your question:**

Yes, you need to define new route like this:

```
resources :advertisements do
  member do
    post 'bid'
  end
end
```

You need to create custom action in your AdvertisementsController which will do that:

```
def bid
  @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
  current_user.bids << Bid.new(advertisement: @advertisement, value: params[:bid])
  # you may also add some value column in bids table, thats up to you
  redirect_to @advertisement
end
```

and form would be like this:

```
<%= form_tag(bid_advertisement_path(@advertisement), :method => "post",) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:bid, "Make a bid:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:bid) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for such descriptive answer , let me try this.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct what you may want to have is a [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) the gem for this can do exactly what you want. I say that you may have to use a nested form because by going by what you are saying a `User` `has_many :bids` which is correct. In order for the bids to accept the attributes from the user you will need to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` on your Bids model. Tried to mock an example together for you

```
<%= form_for bid do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
    <%= user_fields.label :name %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label :product %>
  <%= f.text_field :product %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Relevant links: [196 - Railscasts Nested Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)